# How to use Intellij to generate a gradle file

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I already have an android project, but when I first build it, I do not use gradle.
Right now , so many libs support gradle compile. Is there any way can use the Intellij to generate a build.gradle, and use gradle to compile the project.

Comment: I assume you mean that your original project uses the old Eclipse directory structure and Ant as the build tool. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can either download Android Studio or the Android plugin for IntelliJ. Then you can import your old Eclipse-based or Ant-based project in order to generate a gradle script and rearrange the project into the new directory structure

Comment: Thank you for your help, I still want to use IntelliJ, is there any tutorial for the android plugin.

Comment: @Urchin My understanding is that the Android Plugin makes IntelliJ behave exactly like Android Studio when you open an Android project. The only part that is different is installation.

Comment: @Urchin I just downloaded IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE. It has Android support straight out of the box, so you don't need to download and install anything extra. For older versions, I don't know if the Android plug-in is built-in. You might need to download it from the Plug-ins Manager.

Comment: I use intelliJ13, I check that I have android plugin, but still do not find any generate gradle file option.

Comment: @Urchin I would try to import the Eclipse project.

Comment: Thank you any way, but it still generate a gradle file.